# How to fix crash `*** -[NSObject allocWithZone:]: attempt to allocate object of class 'AGXA12FamilyCommandBuffer' failed`?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, crash, tvos

`*** -[NSObject allocWithZone:]: attempt to allocate an object of class 'AGXA12FamilyCommandBuffer' failed` happens on `tvOS` to many users that use my product.

Does anybody know what this class is `AGXA12FamilyCommandBuffer` and what could cause the crash?

Comment: It's part of Metal. I would expect running out of GPU memory if I had to guess. Could be an OS bug or yours depending on your code. If you're not using Metal directly, or using frameworks that make heavy use of the GPU, I'd reach out to Apple with it.

Comment: Thanks, @RobNapier. Yes is part of Metal, however this bug started in early versions when I wasn't using Metal at all. Must be an OS bug.